# USB networking between Pi Zero and Pi 3 not RUNNING

Tags: pi-3, pi-zero, raspbian-buster

I am struggling to get a Pi3 and a Pi Zero to network over USB. I have followed the advice at https://en.iakta.org/progetti/2raspiviausb/ and https://en.iakta.org/progetti/2raspiviausb/ (and elsewhere) but it is still not working. The two are linked via a USB cable from the Pi Zero micro USB socket (not the power one) to one of the USB sockets on the Pi3 (I have tried all the sockets).

Both Pi's are running Raspbian Buster.

Ultimately, I want to be able to link the ethernet and USB network on the Pi3 so that the Pi Zero can access the internet that way and not use its wifi at all.

On both Pi's, I modified the config.txt file to have the line:

`dtoverlay=dwc2`

and the cmdline.txt file to have:

`modules-load=dwc2,g_ether`

after "rootwait".

On the Pi3, the /etc/network/interfaces file contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback    
auto usb0

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
  address 192.168.42.1
  network 192.168.42.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.42.255

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.201/24
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

The /etc/dhcpcd.conf file has at the end:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.201/24
static routers=192.168.1.254
```

(I assume that these entries are not relevant since interfaces will override it, but I include it here for completeness)

The output of ifconfig and ip link is as follows:

```
$ ifconfig usb0
usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    ether e6:67:a7:df:88:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@banana:~ $ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:67:a7:df:88:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:0d:38:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:58:6d:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 100
    link/none
```

On the Pi Zero, /etc/network/interfaces contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto usb0
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.42.200/24

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

The /etc/dhcpcd.conf file has at the end:

```
interface usb0
static ip_address=192.168.42.200
static routers=192.168.42.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.1
```

(Again, I assume that these lines are ignored)

The output of ifconfig and ip link is as follows:

```
$ ifconfig usb0
usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    ether 22:04:00:17:2a:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@pi-zero:~ $ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:04:00:17:2a:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:4a:ea:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

On both Pi's, ifconfig shows that the link is not RUNNING (but it is UP) while ip link reports NO-CARRIER.

How can I get this working? It looked so easy on the tutorials :(